# Android Add Place to Google Places database doesn't work

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api

I'm developing an android application using Google Maps and Google Places.
When a user makes a long click on the map, I show him a form in which he can add details about his clicked place, and then I want to add it to Google Database as a new Google Place.
This is what I do when before and after he submits the form:

**in onCreate():**

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, 0, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
```

**after submitting the form:**

```
private void addPlaceToGoogleDbAndToTrip()
{
    final Double lat = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("lat");
    final Double lng = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("lng");
    final String placeName = newPlaceNameET.getText().toString();
    final String address = newPlaceAddressET.getText().toString();
    final String website = newPlaceWebsiteET.getText().toString();
    final String phoneNumber = newPlacePhoneET.getText().toString();
    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

AddPlaceRequest place =
        new AddPlaceRequest(
                placeName, // Name
                latlng, // Latitude and longitude
                address, // Address
                Collections.singletonList(Place.TYPE_POINT_OF_INTEREST), // Place types
                phoneNumber, // Phone number
                Uri.parse("www.SomeWebsite.co.il") // Website
        );

Places.GeoDataApi.addPlace(mGoogleApiClient, place).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>()
{
    @Override
    public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places)
    {

        if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " + places.getStatus().toString());
            places.release();
            return;
        }

        final Place place = places.get(0);
        newPlaceID = place.getId();
        Log.i(TAG, "Place add result: " + place.getName());
        places.release();

    }
});
}
```

but **places.get(0)** used to return an empty place, and now I don't even get that... I get an Error on the result coming back back. it says: "ERROR_OPERATION_FAILED, resolution=null".

my manifest has this as well:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Any idea what might be the problem? The APIs are enabled in my developers console.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you may need `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY` rather than `com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY`

Comment: Ok, I switched `com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY` with `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY` and everything works great!
I used my Android key and the maps are still working with the new line in the manifest. Thank you very much @spiv

Comment: Great!  I guess I should add that as the answer then :)

Comment: The [Place Add](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) has been deprecated on June 30, 2017 and will stop working on June 30, 2018. So you cannot use this method anymore. For further details please refer to the corresponding [geo blog post](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/06/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY` rather than `com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY`.

Comment: As mentioned above, it solved the issue :) Do you have any idea if and when will my personal added places appear in the Google Places autocomplete search results?