# Google Places API - any way to enumerate the Place Types list?

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

My question is in the context of an Android app providing users with a way to add Places to the Google Places database.  Regarding this page:

https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types

After extensive searching, I've been unable to find a way to retrieve these types from the API in a manner suitable for presentation to the user.  Does anyone know a way to accomplish this, or is there a built-in dialog I can call (similar to the Place Picker)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to get places using google API ? according to the device location ?

Comment: @Stallion My issue is related to adding places to Google, not retrieving them.  I've successfully implemented Place Picker for that, and it works very well.  But to add a place, Google requires that I pass a "type" integer to distinguish what kind of place I'm adding (restaurant, store, etc), but they give me no way to enumerate the valid types into a list (at least, no way that I can find - hence the question).

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to add a place to Google's database?  Are you using this? https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place

Comment: @DanielNugent I would gladly share my code, except it isn't written.  The design of my code depends on the answer to my question.  Also, this is an Android app, not a web service.  I would use the example from [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/add-place), except the problem described above would still exist

Comment: Ahh, yes.  Well, it looks like they're defined in the Place interface as static int constants.  Take a look at this question, and where it uses `Place.TYPE_POINT_OF_INTEREST`  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698094/android-add-place-to-google-places-database-doesnt-work   Full list here:  https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place

Comment: I suppose if all else fails, I could hard-code the place type to something generic like they did - I had just hoped to provide the user with a list of types, and let them choose one or more.  What it's looking like is that I will have to roll this myself using custom objects, if nobody knows a trick to extract the types.  That just more stuff to maintain as Google adds & drops types from the list, but oh well.  :)

Comment: @Joel  I would just give the user a list of some common ones, and then "other", and just use `Place.TYPE_POINT_OF‌​_INTEREST` for the "other" option.

Comment: @DanielNugent That sounds like a winning idea in the absence of a "proper" solution.  Thanks for all your input!  :)

Answer (score 2):

I see this is old so you've likely worked around your issue by now.  For the benefit of others, here's a work around since Google seems to have left us dangling on this one.

First, I've created a small data file having all of Google's constants (as of this posting date) associated with friendly names.  The two values are separated by commas.

Here's a link to the file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_33r2IAzcMibndhT2RicWdLUXc

This file can be formatted in JSON if you wish, or read as is.  Use it as a source for an  AutoCompleteTextView DataAdapter, so the users can easily select a place type.  I haven't written the code yet. My needs are different than yours so my code won't meet your needs, but it should be pretty easy to implement an AutoCompleteTextView with this data.